# DataMember return null

Tags: wcf, soapui, datacontract, datamember

I use SoapUI to test my web service. The point is that is not taking the value of some tag, i.e,

`<con:customerLastName>Smith</con:customerLastName>
 <con:customerFirstName>John</con:customerFirstName>`

I don't know reason but alway DataMember customerFirstName return null

My contract.cs

```
[DataContract]
public class recordParameter
{
  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  public string customerLastName { get; set; }
  [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
  public string customerFirstName { get; set; }
 }
```

My ws.cs

```
case "customerData":
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.parameters.record.customerLastName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.parameters.record.customerFirstName)){
```